# Can we call CSS in Wordpress plugin with custom function and call in file

Tags: wordpress

```
function Custom_style_for_code(){ ?>
        <style>
        .container{
        //css goes here
        font-weight:bold;

        }
           </style><?php }

Custom_style_for_code();
```

I want to call styles in plugin page with function like that can we call styles like this.Does Wordpress Accept this

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
class Admin {
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', [ &$this, 'load_styles' ] );
    }
    public function load_styles() {
        if ( $this->is_plugin_page() ) {
            wp_enqueue_style(...);
        }
    }
    private function is_plugin_page(): bool {
        //All conditions for you plugin
        return ! empty ( $_GET['page'] ) && 'plugin-name' == $_GET['page'] ? true : false;
    }
}
```

Use current conditions in `is_plugin_page`

Comment: "is_plugin_page " checkes directory   for current page of my plugin ? as per wordpress norm this function deprecated https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_plugin_page/

Comment: it's method of the class. You can change whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should be enqueuing your styles using the built-in functionality for loading stylesheets rather than trying to force-print inline styling. If it's for a plugin page, then you should use `admin_enqueue_scripts`:

```
function vnm_load_my_css($hook) {

    //  Check if the passed $hook matches your plugin - no point enqueuing your CSS across all of the admin

    if ($hook == 'myplugin') {

        //  This assumes a path relative to your plugin file; so if your file is in /myplugin/ then your CSS will be in /myplugin/css/

        $cssPath = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/css/';
        $cssURI = plugins_url('/css/', __FILE__);

        wp_enqueue_style('my-plugin-style', $cssURI . '/mystyles.css');
    }
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'vnm_load_my_css', 20, 1);
```

Comment: i have include these files but after plugin main page they are not working . i have multiple page in my plugin.

Comment: @Vaibhav without seeing what you're doing, it's impossible to diagnose. First, take out that `if ()` statement. Then try adding `echo '<pre style="padding-left:15rem;">' . $hook . '</pre>';` before the `if()` statement to see what your hook is like; if all your plugin pages share a common hook (e.g. `strpos('myplugin_') !== false`), then use that as your conditional. Otherwise I would recommend posting a new question.

Comment: Yes i know that without viewing code it is quite difficult i will upload my code on Github  i have upgrading code of following plugin you will get some idea with this plugin made by me now as per wordpress norms i am upgrading i will upload ASAP. https://github.com/Viv31/Wordpress_CRUD_Plugin/blob/master/CRUD-Plugin/alluser.php